# Are there any Christian counterparts to Ashirra?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

I have been reading on the Ashirra in the Vampire the Masquerade. They seem to be vampires who believe that following Islam will grant them salvation(Or at least follow it for the sake of convenience.) which allows them to unite under one banner similar to Sabbat and the Camarilla.

What I wish to ask is that is there a Christian counterpart of Ashirra made out of vampires that believe recognizing the word of Jesus will grant them salvation?

Note that I am referring to the timeline of anniversary edition and while I am aware of Cainite Heresy which aims to subvert Christianity to serve vampires I was looking for a group that truly believes(Or at least claims to believe.) rather than pragmatic vampires with blood cults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Such groups exist, but they’re small.

The Ashirra are the predominant sect in the Muslim world. By contrast, the belief that the Kindred are damned or cursed by the Divine is so widespread (and reinforced in a variety of ways by both the Camarilla and the Sabbat) that groups that believe in the potential salvation of vampires function as small cults.

The primary source on them is the *Vampire Revised* book *[State of Grace](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/272/State-of-Grace)*. Among them, you'll find the Custodians of the Commandments, which is closest to the kind of group you want, and the Redeemers of the Damned, which are mainly about achieving redemption by helping ghosts.

Answer (score 2):

Road of Haven or Via Caeli is probably what you are looking for.
You can found everything in depths inside Vampire : Dark Ages 20th Anniversary or older edition, if I recall correctly there is even a dedicated book for it.

If I'm not wrong the rulebook even suggest that usually Ashirra are themselves followers of the Road of Haven.

Comment: I believe Road Of Heaven is one of the paths rather than a fully dedicated organization but I will check it out.

Comment: Roads are organizations! Or at least they were back in Dark Ages. Every Road have an internal hierarchy and rites. Is not only a personal moral code, but a "Belief" - similar to a Religion - that many cainites follows and, as such, it has a structure. If you want a "bunch of vampires who belives that God will save them", it's probably what you were looking for! I checked anyway and there is indeed a a sourcebook called Road of Haven that explain even the factions inside it!